# What is the problem in this code this is showing (";" expected) error. PS: i m a beginner

Tags: java, conditional-statements

```
import java.util.*;
class Main
    {    public static void main(String args[]){ 
    int n = 3;
    if (n%2==0){
        if (2<=n<=5){
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
        elseif (6<=n<=20){
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }
        elseif(n>20){ 
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }

       }
    }
```

// this code is showing ";" expected can somebody plz point out the mistake for me
// i m a beginner 
// this code compare a no and checks whether it is odd or even

Comment: There should be space between else and if here `elseif`. If it's not copy paste mistake!

Comment: also `if (2<=n<=5){` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: In the future please show where the error is. The compiler is telling you anyway, so why not help us help you and avoid a treasure hunt in your code? :)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, if (2<=n<=5) does not work. Use

```
if (n >= 2 && n <= 5)
```

instead.

In addition, there should be a space in `else if`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 3;
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            if (n >= 2 && n <= 5) {
                System.out.println("Not Weird");
            } else if (n >= 6 && n <= 20) {
                System.out.println("Weird");
            } else if (n > 20) {
                System.out.println("Not Weird");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A minor nitpick: `if (2 <= n && n <= 5) {` it took me a while to notice this *wasn't* wrong. I would have written `if (2 <= n && 5 >= n) {` but maybe it's just me

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Whether you use `2 <= n` or `n >= 2` and `n <= 5` or `5 >= n` doesn't really matter. Given OP's original code, I think `2 <= n && n <= 5` makes more sense in this case. And personally I usually put the variable I want to check first and the variable itself after, so for me it would become `n >= 2 && n <= 5`. But again, it doesn't matter and it's just personal preference for everyone. If you prefer `2 <= n && 5 >= n` that's completely fine, but `2 <= n && n <= 5` makes more sense here based on the original `2 <= n <= 5` code in my opinion.

Comment: I agree. It's a matter of style, and I think  `if (n >= 2 && n <= 5)` is better.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen as I said, nitpicking and probably just me :)